# Cross stack reference from 2 different AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I saw that you could store the attributes from stack A in a parameter store created in Acc B and use dynamic references in stack B to fetch the values from the store.

I created a parameter store in account B via CFN, and can use dynamic references to fetch the valu

How do I store the attribute from stack A in account B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your own [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) for that. It would be in the form of a lambda function, which you would develop and program to access other account and return what you need to your first account.